# Find and replace using parts of the found string in the replace string

Tags: sed, find, regular-expression, console, replace

Let `foo` be any string. I have to search a file for all occurrences of

```
   \LeftLabel{foo}
```

and replace each occurrence with

```
   \LeftLabel{\textsf{foo}}
```

but only if foo does not start with a `$` character. How?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's consider this test file:

```
$ cat file
\LeftLabel{foo}
\LeftLabel{$foo}
LeftLabel{foo}
```

Now, let's make the substitution:

```
$ sed -E 's|\\LeftLabel\{([^$}][^}]*)\}|\\LeftLabel{\\textsf{\1}}|g' file
\LeftLabel{\textsf{foo}}
\LeftLabel{$foo}
LeftLabel{foo}
```

#### How it works

The substitute command in `sed` looks like `s|old|new|g` where `old` is a regular expression, `new` is what to substitute in its place and the final `g` tells sed to replace all such occurrences on a line, not just the first.

In our command, the `old` part looks like:

```
\\LeftLabel\{([^$}][^}]*)\}
```

This matches `\LeftLabel{` followed by any character other than `$` or `}`, that is `[^$}]`, followed by any number of any characters not `}`, that is `[^}]*`, followed by a `}`. Notice that some of those characters have to have a backslash in front of them so that sed treats them as normal characters, not regex-active characters.  Notice also that the characters inside the curly braces are enclosed in parentheses.  The parenthesis are regex-active characters which tell sed to save what's inside them as group 1.  We can reference these characters as `\1`  in the `new` part of the command.